# How can I tell which version of a dependency was pulled?

Tags: go

In `main.go` I have this import statement:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "strings"
    "syscall"
    "github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo"
)
```

And I'm running into a bug that is supposed to be fixed in the more recent versions of this dependency.  **How can I determine what version was pulled in when I built my docker container that I deployed?**

In GoLand it doesn't show any external dependencies:

[image]

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.12-alpine
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD src/ /app

ENV CGO_ENABLED=0
ENV GO111MODULE=off

# Fetch application dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache --update git \
    && go get github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo \
    && go get github.com/jonas747/dshardmanager \
    && go get github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-go \
    && apk del git

# Build binary
RUN go build -o main .

CMD ["/app/main"]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple ways you can go about this. When you run `go get remote/path/to/lib`, it installs that to `$GOPATH/src/remote/path/to/lib`, so if you `cd` into that path and run `git describe --tags`, you'll see the latest version pulled. However, if you manage your project with go modules, you should be able to see the version you're using in the `go.mod` file after the dependency name.

So, in essence:
`go get github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo && cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo && git describe --tags` should be the quick and dirty way to find what version you're using for this specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an updated version of your package try using `go get -u <package>`

Or maybe use dependency management such as `dep`. (https://github.com/golang/dep) 
You can specify your versions in your `Gopkg.toml`.

Or `go modules` if you are using version 1.11 or higher for golang.

Answer (score 0):

I see your GoLand SDK is in different version with your Docker.
If you use 1.12, you can try to use go module. It will generate a file go.mod, which will describe your package and version, and better management. For example:

```
module github.com/example

require (
    github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go v0.0.0-20190104215108-45d0c5e3638e
    github.com/buger/jsonparser v0.0.0-20181115193947-bf1c66bbce23
    github.com/gorilla/context v1.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.6.2
    github.com/patrickmn/go-cache v2.1.0+incompatible
    github.com/prometheus/client_golang v0.9.2
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.3.0
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20181220203305-927f97764cc3
    golang.org/x/sync v0.0.0-20181221193216-37e7f081c4d4 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20180909124046-d0be0721c37e // indirect
    gopkg.in/resty.v1 v1.12.0
)
```